# Why is 'res' not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a bot using discord.js. I'm trying to setup a system where the bot is allowed to send a message as long as it is not blacklisted. However, every time I run the function, I get this message: `ReferenceError: res is not defined`

I've tried moving `var res` so many times and I can't figure it out. Does anyone know how to arrange this properly?

```
function getNum() {

    var randNum = [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
    ];
    // Blacklist Entries Start
    var blacklistNum = [
        "1"
    ];
    // Blacklist Entries End
    return randNum[Math.floor(Math.random()*randNum.length)];
    return;
}
if(res === blacklistNum) {
    getNum();
}

getNum();
message.channel.send(res);
```

Comment: because you declare it inside a function

Answer (score 2):

`res` is only available in your function scope. Either you define it globally or you return it from your function.